# How to read excel file using spring boot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot

I am making a spring boot application which will take the excel file and store its content and store it in database. I have tried many ways..but not successful. Does anyone have an idea about how to do this.
I don't know how to make the controller for importing the excel file. And is there any dependency which I have to include for reading data from excel file

Comment: Use Apache Poi with XSSF part.

Comment: Do you want to store the file in the database or its contents in tables?

Comment: i want its content in tables.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Html file for uploading the form is

```
<form th:action="@{/import}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" th:name="file" />
    <input th:type="submit" value="Import" />
</form>
```

Controller class is

```
@PostMapping("/import")
public void mapReapExcelDatatoDB(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile reapExcelDataFile) throws IOException {
    
    List<Test> tempStudentList = new ArrayList<Test>();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(reapExcelDataFile.getInputStream());
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    for(int i=1;i<worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() ;i++) {
        Test tempStudent = new Test();
            
        XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            
        tempStudent.setId((int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
        tempStudent.setContent(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        tempStudentList.add(tempStudent);   
    }
}
```

Make sure to add the dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<!-- excel 2007 over-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it will work fine.

Comment: can you paste your pom.xml file here?

Comment: Thank you for this amazing solution.

Answer (score 9):

Use Apache POI library which is easily available using Maven Dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Code to read file**

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ApachePOIExcelRead {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                    //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
                    if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Please modify above program as per your requirement.
If you know your excel file column index then you can direct row to read cell e.g.`row.getCell(0)` where `row` object like `XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();`

Hope this will helps you

[Reference](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```
    <form th:action="@{/import}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" th:name="file">

    <input th:type="submit" value="Import" />
```

```
    @PostMapping("/import")
    public void mapReapExcelDatatoDB(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile reapExcelDataFile) throws IOException {

       List<Test> tempStudentList = new ArrayList<Test>();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(reapExcelDataFile.getInputStream());
        XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for(int i=1;i<worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() ;i++) {
            Test tempStudent = new Test();

            XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);

            tempStudent.setId((int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
            tempStudent.setContent(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                tempStudentList.add(tempStudent);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also good to add this **dependency** too:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```