# insert data from excel into database using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I suppose to insert the excel sheet data into database using spring boot but i don't know how mainly i'm not gonna insert all the columns from the excel file ,only the columns i need to use.
I don't know how to start .So can anyone help me please?

Comment: you can read excel file using Apache POI library. https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel#1-reading-from-excel is a good link to start with POI for excel.

Comment: A suggestion which may or may not work - you may be able to convert the excel file to CSV format so its easier to work with.

Comment: ok thank you . I'm gonna try

Answer (score 1):

Use POI library to read Data and dump it to DB through a connection. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849800/how-to-read-excel-file-using-spring-boot).